# Copy dates in a pivot table where the day is less than 10 and paste-values to a data table without leading zeros being removed?

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, pivot-table

*First of all, I apologise if this question has existed before. I couldn't find what I was looking for in the suggestions list for similar questions and even after various google searches.*

In Excel (2016+) using VBA, I am trying to copy a range of data from a pivot-table and paste values into a separate workbook sheet under a data-table, while keeping and utilising the formats already within that table.

To explain further, the first column in my pivot-table has dates in the format of dd-mmm-yy, which shows as 08-July-20. The dates in my data-table are also formatted in the same way. However, when data is copied from my pivot-table and pasted as values into the data-table, the date changes format to d-mmm-yy, showing as 8-July-20.

I would like to know if there is a way to **prevent** the date format changing from dd-mmm-yy to d-mmm-yy.

It could simply have something to do with the pivot-table formats/settings, or the data-table formats are causing this issue, but I wanted to pick someone else's brain because I think I've gone wrong somewhere.

Alternatively, I could create an additional pointer to capture the newest last row after data is pasted. Then with this pointer and my other pointer, they can create a range where the code re-formats it to dd-mmm-yy. However, I don't think it should have to come to that.

This is what it looks like when the data is pasted in

[image]

### Below is the code I wrote and use for this process.

```
Sub subShowcase()
    
    ' ### PHASE 1 ###
    
    ' Code where data is imported into the raw data tabs of the pivot workbook
    
    ' ### PHASE 2 ###
    
    ' Initialise variables
    Dim contactWkb, pivotWkb As Workbook
    Dim pivotLastRow, contactLastRow As Long
    Dim filePath As String
    
    filePath = "C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\"
    
    ' Set Pivot file
    Set pivotWkb = Workbooks("TEMPLATE Contact PIVOT.xlsx")
    
    ' Refresh pivots
    pivotWkb.RefreshAll
    
    ' Locate range of data
    With pivotWkb.Worksheets("Pivot")
        pivotLastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    End With
    
    ' Open Contact file
    Set contactWkb = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "Contact.xlsx", 3, Local:=True)
    
    ' Copy pivot table data and paste values to Contact file
    contactLastRow = contactWkb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    With pivotWkb.Worksheets("Pivot")
        ' Open, first range
        .Range("A6:C" & pivotLastRow).Copy
        contactWkb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & contactLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        ' Several other copies from the pivotWkb to other contact workbooks
    End With
    
    ' Save & Close Contact file
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    contactWkb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    ' Close pivot file
    pivotWkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Msgbox when done
    MsgBox "Contact file has been successfully updated"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The leading zeros are either part of a string that looks like a date, or they are there because of cell formatting. You can easily enough just format the column and it will affect only the actual date values and not the strings (if they are strings)

Comment: @braX The pivot-table dates point to more data-tables where the data is a formula using TODAY() and another similar one that uses TODAY() to calculate the last weekday. There are three separate pivots and two of them are having this issue. The one that isn't is because the date is formatted as dd-mm-yyyy (08-07-2020) using a formula to reformat it as TEXT(DATEVALUE(TEXT([@[Date Raised]],"dd-mm-yyyy")),"dd-mm-yyyy") where the data-table's Date Raised column is pointing to dates formatted as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm. The two pivots having this issue are not strings.